# Failed to deploy Azure Function using Aure Container Registry

Tags: azure, azure-functions, containers, azure-container-registry

Our team has set up an ansible-playbook to deploy Azure Function using this [reference](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/07/03/Linux-container-from-ACR-with-private-endpoint.html#advanced-scenarios). We use a user assigned identity to pull the function app image from an ACR like the following:

```yaml
- name: Force Login using identity
  command: az login --identity

- name: Get subscriptionId
  command: az account show --query id --output tsv
  register: subscriptionId

- name: Get functionapp identity's clientId
  command: az identity show --resource-group "{{ functionapp_resource_group }}" --name "{{ functionapp_user_identity }}" --query clientId --output tsv
  register: identityId

- name: Use functionapp identity for acr pull
  command:
    az resource update
    --ids /subscriptions/{{ subscriptionId.stdout }}/resourceGroups/{{ functionapp_resource_group }}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{{ functionapp_name }}/config/web
    --set properties.acrUseManagedIdentityCreds=True
    --set properties.AcrUserManagedIdentityID={{ identityId.stdout }}

- name: Config the functionapp
  command:
    az functionapp config appsettings set --name "{{ functionapp_name }}"
    --resource-group "{{ functionapp_resource_group }}"
    --settings
    "Key1={{ Value1 }}"
    "Key2={{ Value2 }}"

- name: Deploy the functionapp
  command:
    az functionapp config container set --name "{{ functionapp_name }}"
    --resource-group "{{ functionapp_resource_group }}"
    --docker-custom-image-name "{{ docker_registry_host }}/{{ image_name }}:{{ image_tag }}"
    --docker-registry-server-url "{{ docker_registry_host }}"
```

Usually, the script works fine. The successful deployment log should be like the following:

[image]

However, we encountered a strange failure today. When deploying the image, the Azure Portal shows an incomplete log:

[image]

Does anyone know why this failure occurred?

Comment: You can make use of this [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/get-container-logs-zip) to download the zip file of container logs  or if it is hosted on linux/custom containers you can look at the deployment logs using this url `https://<app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/<deploymentId>` 
Refer to documentation for more information on [how to access logfiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#access-log-files)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't encounter this problem again. I'll check scm out if this problem occurs another day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out that it may imply there's no further docker log today.